# Usando JOIN com funcao HQL no NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Estou tentando executar um JOIN usando HQL com NHibernate e retorna uma lista vazia. Como fazer isso ?

Estou tentando assim.

```
[Serializable]
public class Cliente {
    public virtual int id               { set; get; }
    public virtual string nome          { set; get; }
    public virtual string cpf           { set; get; }
    public virtual DateTime nascimento  { set; get; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Conta {    
    public virtual long id                      { set; get; }
    public virtual Cliente cliente              { set; get; }
    public virtual String historico             { set; get; }
    public virtual DateTime dtLancamento        { set; get; }
    public virtual DateTime dtVencimento        { set; get; }
    public virtual decimal valorFinal           { set; get; }
}
```

**DAO**

```
//JOIN
public IList<Conta> findAllContasReceberAtiva() 
{
      ISession _session = getSession();
      IList<Conta> list = _session.CreateQuery("FROM Conta c " +
          " INNER JOIN c.cliente cli ON (c.cliente.id = cli.id) " +  
          " WHERE (c.tipoConta = 1) AND (c.status = 0) ORDER BY c.dtLancamento ")
         .List<Conta>();
      return list;    
}
```

Comment: Se você fizesse a relação _one-to-many_ no mapeamento do Cliente e _many-to-one_ na Conta acho que seria mais fácil.. não precisaria escrever o sql... se quiser posso por exemplo de como mapear..

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni sim sim, concordo. É que é um trabalho de faculdade que o professor pediu um `JOIN` e vc ja viu neh, explicar pra professor que é autojoin demora anossss...kkk. Mas ja consegui fazer aqui. Obrigado

Comment: @FernandoPaiva coloque a sua solução como resposta.